# unsigned long long int strange behaviour

Tags: c

this C code

```
unsigned long int a, b, x;
float c, d, y;

a = 6;
b = 2;
x = a/b;

c = 6.0;
d = 2.0;
y = c/d;

printf("\n x: %d \n y: %f \n",x,y);
```

works correctly and prints out

```
x: 3 
y: 3.000000
```

however, when I change the first line to this

```
unsigned long long int a, b, x;
```

I get this output:

```
x: 3 
y: 0.000000
```

this really boggles me... I haven't changed anything with c,d, and y - why am I getting this? I'm using gcc on linux

Comment: The display specifier `%d` is incorrect, use `%llu` instead.

Comment: If you compiler doesn't warn you about this, you should check the with which arguments you invoke it.

Comment: I don't pass it any arguments... should I?

Comment: With gcc you should always use -Wall and -O2 isn't bad either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the latter one use:

```
printf("\n x: %llu \n y: %f \n",x,y);
```

Use `u` for unsigned integrals (your output is only correct because you use small values). Use the `ll` modifier for long longs otherwise printf will use the wrong size for decoding the second parameter (x) for printf, so it uses bad address to fetch y.

Comment: also for first one should be printf("\n x: %u \n y: %f \n",x,y);

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
printf("\n x: %llu \n y: %f \n", x, y);
```

Otherwise something like this will happen (example is for system where `unsigned long int` is 4 byte, `unsigned long long int` is 8 byte and `float` is 4 byte):

1. `[[03 00 00 00] (unsigned long int) [3.0] (float)]` everything is correct, you print two 4 byte values.
2. `[[03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00] (unsigned long long int) [3.0] (float)]` here, you print two 4 print values, but actually in the buffer that your `printf` received there is one 8 byte value and one 4 byte value, so you prints only first 8 bytes :)